# AKS unable to recognize any kubectl commands

Tags: azure, kubernetes, github-actions, azure-aks, kubeconfig

I'm currently trying to deploy two microservices to my AKS cluster using github actions. 
(I've already tried deploying it to `minikube`, which worked flawlessly).

**The process:**

1. Build docker images and push to dockerhub
2. Login using `azure/login@1.4.6`
3. Setup kubectl using `azure/setup-kubectl@v2.0`
4. Deploy the microservices simply using `kubectl apply -f ./service-1/k8s`

*Note: `./service-1/k8s/` includes `service.yaml`, `ingress.yaml` & `deployment.yaml`, which all work correctly when deployed to minikube using the exact same process (minus az-specific steps).*

Now then, the problem arises up on using (any) `kubectl` command. The error in the console is the following:

```bash
E0118 [time]    1792 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0118 [time]    1792 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0118 [time]    1792 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
unable to recognize "service-1/k8s/deployment.yaml": Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
unable to recognize "service-1/k8s/ingress.yaml": Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
unable to recognize "service-1/k8s/service.yaml": Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Sadly I have no idea what this error means.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you run as part of your pipeline the command az aks get-credentials ? Between steps 2 and 3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-get-credentials

Comment: @Hackerman Yup. I did. Supplying `CLUSTER_NAME` and `RESOURCE_GROUP`.

Comment: Are you using service principal to login? Also did you try adding the admin flag to the az aks get-credentials command? Please add you GH actions yaml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you're encountering indicate that `kubectl` is trying to communicate with a Kubernetes cluster API server at `localhost:8080`, which is the default when no context is set, and it's failing to connect. This suggests that `kubectl` is not configured with the correct context to your AKS cluster.

In your GitHub Actions workflow, after setting up `kubectl` with `azure/setup-kubectl@v2.0`, you need to ensure that `kubectl` is configured to use the credentials for your AKS cluster. Typically, this is done by using the `az aks get-credentials` command with Azure CLI, which automatically sets the correct context in `kubectl` to communicate with your AKS cluster.

Here's what you need to do in your GitHub Actions workflow to correct this:

After logging in with `azure/login@1.4.6`, fetch the credentials for your AKS cluster using Azure CLI:

```
- name: Get AKS credentials
  run: az aks get-credentials --resource-group <YourResourceGroupName> --name <YourClusterName> --overwrite-existing
```

Confirm that the `kubectl` context has been set to your AKS cluster:

```
- name: Check kubectl context
  run: kubectl config current-context
```

[image]

Apply your Kubernetes manifests with `kubectl`:

```
- name: Deploy to AKS
  run: kubectl apply -f ./service-1/k8s/
```

[image]

Here, I have already added the $rg, $clustername and $creds seperately in variables.
Now I don't know If you're using a service principal to authenticate with Azure, if so, then ensure that the service principal has the necessary permissions to fetch credentials for the AKS cluster and perform the required operations.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "APIM" --scope /subscriptions/<yoursubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<yourRG> --role Contributor --json-auth
```

[image]

Verify that the Azure credentials stored in GitHub Secrets (`$creds`) have the correct format and contain all required fields (`clientId`, `clientSecret`, `subscriptionId`, `tenantId`).

[image]

and last but not least, verify that the Kubernetes API server is running by checking the status of the `kube-apiserver` pod using the

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

[image]

By ensuring `kubectl` is correctly pointed at your AKS cluster, it should resolve the connection issues and allow your deployments to proceed.

Kindly refer to below documentation for ease as it has demonstrated step by step process with example-

[Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Services using GitHub Actions](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/wiki/Deployment-With-GitHub-Actions)

[Official MS Doc to build, test and deploy container images to AKS using github action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-action)

[Similar issue resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/612656/unable-to-connect-aks-cluster-using-github-actions)

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your help! Although the cause of the problem was rather stupid and the fix for it was to just _Start the AKS cluster on Azure itself_, your solution was and might be very helpful for others! :D